# php file not able to upload in .net application, permission issue

Tags: php, iis

I have a php file in a folder C:\Myfolder and all files are here (html,aspx). When i type the application url\index.html page works fine

bt if i give index.php its saying page not found. My php file only contains "hi" message right now.

I guess IIS server is not recognizing the php files.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server can actually run php files. It may just not know what to do with it.